# How do I go about session handling considering my approach?

Tags: express, authentication, session, cookies

I currently have a decent authentication logic in place which will verify credentials against the database document/entry.

Once a login request has a successful response, I set a httpOnly cookie including the unique userID and I return the user as a response to the client. The client however can not read/write to the httpOnly cookie, so I currently check if the httpOnly cookie is valid (based on it's value and expiration). I have a middleware that rejects or forwards requests based on the httpOnly cookie validity.

**[Potential solution]:**
I could have the client side hit a specific endpoint that checks the validity of the cookie, and if it's valid it will grab and return the user matching the cookie value (userID). This means every navigation change or endpoint being hit, the client sends a request to the server to check the cookie first. Long story short: all web application navigation and API requests will be preceded by a API request to check the cookie validity.

```js
  public login = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> => {
    try {
      const { username, password } = req.body;
      const serviceResponse = await this.authService.login({
        username: username,
        password: password,
      });

      if (serviceResponse.error) {
        // Something went wrong, expose error to client.
        res.status(serviceResponse.code).json(serviceResponse);
      } else {
        // Authentication succeeced!
        this.setHttpCookie(res, serviceResponse.data['id']);
        res.status(serviceResponse.code).json(serviceResponse);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof Error) {
        const errorResponse: ResponseInterface = {
          data: null,
          error: true,
          message: error.message,
          code: 400,
        };
        res.status(errorResponse.code).json(errorResponse);
      } else {
        // Let Express handle the error for now:
        next(error);
      }
    }
  };
```

And here's my middleware, to give you an idea of what I'm doing at the moment:

```js
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';
import UserModel from '../models/user.model';
import { COOKIE_NAME_AUTH } from '../config';
import { ResponseInterface } from '../interfaces/response.interface';

const AuthenticationMiddleware = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  try {
    const cookieValue = req.cookies[`${COOKIE_NAME_AUTH}`];
    console.log(cookieValue);

    if (!cookieValue) {
      throw new Error('Cookie expired or is empty. Access has been denied!');
    }

    const user = await UserModel.findById(cookieValue);

    if (!user) {
      // Can happen if the user has been deleted from the DB.
      throw new Error('Can not verify the cookie value. Access has been denied!');
    }
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof Error) {
      const errorResponse: ResponseInterface = {
        data: null,
        error: true,
        message: error.message,
        code: 400,
      };
      res.status(errorResponse.code).json(errorResponse);
    } else {
      // Let Express handle the error for now:
      next(error);
    }
  }
};

export default AuthenticationMiddleware;
```

Comment: The session cookie must be checked by the _server_ before it accepts any request from the client. This check protects the server against requests from malicious clients, because only the legitimate client has the session cookie. But this check must be made for _every_ request, the seperate request you propose is not sufficient to protect the server. You also seem to say that the client also wants to check the cookie for itself, but I see no reason why that would be necessary. Regarding the user ID: the server should send that in the payload of the response that also sets the session cookie.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen My client can't check the cookie, it's a httpOnly cookie. Every request coming from my client will hit the middleware first (which checks the validity of the cookie). The separate request I'm proposing is basically going to be doing what the middleware is doing right now (rejects requests on invalid cookie), except it will have it's own endpoint that the client can directly hit.

Comment: Please explain why you think you need this separate request. The request that you make afterwards already involves checking the cookie.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen When my web application client loads, I want to send a request to the specific session endpoint to see if there's already an existing session. Each time I navigate my web application, I do not necessarily interact with any API routes (which also check my cookie). So I am trying to retrieve the session from the server each time the navigation/route changes (SPA).